# JS : How to get the position of the selection counting HTML tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection, frontend

I'm trying to get the position of my current selection (highlighted) by a start / end array.

As you can see in the snippet, I have success to get my selection position but it doesn't count the HTML Markup.

```js
(function ($) {
  $('#myButton').click(function () {
    var el = document.getElementById('maDiv');
    var sel = getSelectionCharOffsetsWithin(el);
    var string = "Start at : " + sel.start + " | End at : " + sel.end + "\n";

    $('#log').append(string);
  });
})(jQuery);

function getSelectionCharOffsetsWithin(element) {
  var start = 0,
    end = 0;
  var sel, range, priorRange;
  if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
    range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    priorRange = range.cloneRange();
    priorRange.selectNodeContents(element);
    priorRange.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
    start = priorRange.toString().length;
    end = start + range.toString().length;
  } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" &&
    (sel = document.selection).type != "Control") {
    range = sel.createRange();
    priorRange = document.body.createTextRange();
    priorRange.moveToElementText(element);
    priorRange.setEndPoint("EndToStart", range);
    start = priorRange.text.length;
    end = start + range.text.length;
  }
  return {
    start: start,
    end: end
  };
}
```

```css
#maDiv {
  border: 1px dashed #333;
  padding: 15px;
}

#explaination {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<small>Please highlight some text and click the button</small>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="maDiv">lorem <b>ipsum</b> dolor sit amet.</div>
<button id="myButton">Click after select</button>
<div id="explaination">
  if i'm highlighting "lorem" word, i'm waiting : start = 0 | end = 5.
  <br/> if i'm highlighting "ipsum" word, i'm waiting : start = 8 | end = 18
  <br/> if i'm highlighting "sit" word, i'm waiting : start = 24 | end = 28
</div>
<h1>Log :</h1>
<pre id="log"></pre>
```

Link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mr_DeLeTeD/L281hvdL/

Comment: I was looking for to way for fix : https://github.com/timdown/rangy but without results (maybe a bad use of this lib) and i'm trying ton reset the current selection on an other string that contain all the HTML markup